# SQL Server 2008 varchar and char not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I get an error saying `varchar` or `char` is not a recognized in SQL Server. However I use the same software, SQL Server 2008 in college, so I do not want to go for a different version of SQL Server. Anyway I can fix this?

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 26302

```
create table abc 
(
    id int,
    name  varchar(15)
)
```

Error is:

> The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = varchar
>   ]

Comment: If it is a CE release, use nvarchar instead of varchar.

Comment: Yeah. nchar works. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`varchar(n)` is not supported in `SQL Server Compact`. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(v=sql.100).aspx) is the full list of types supported.

Following are the types that you can use.

```
nvarchar(n)
nchar(n)
ntext
```

So you might need to change to `nvarchar(10)`, `nvarchar(5)` and `nchar(1)` etc..

Comment: @IhsanIzwer Glad this worked.. Accept the answer pls.

Comment: Ah i see, you are using SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 0):

Really ? , i tried it, also i tried in creating temp table, it seems both are ok.

```
    create table abc (id int, name varchar(15))

    create table #tmp (id int, name varchar(15))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66b44

Comment: that's the problem. It works in college, VArRCHAR and CHAR. but not here.

Comment: @IhsanIzwer , you are using SQL Server 2008 right ? , that seems working on mine.. sqlfiddle sample in my answer above, are you sure you are working in SQL Server 2008 ?

Comment: @JapzDivino compact has this problem. Varchar is not supported there.

Comment: @AmneshGoel , Ah i see. Thanks